# Aim to or Aim for in this context?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context, to-infinitive, for

Is it correct to use aim **for** in this context? or rather I should write aim **to**?.

.Firstly, the MSc in ecology at the Kora University shares the same focus my bachelor in ecology has. Both aim **for** alternatives to balance the economic development of societies with the sustainable consumption of natural resources.

Comment: You aim _for_ something (noun), or _to_ do something (verb).

Comment: @KateBunting So **for** is correct because is acting as a noun in this context.

Comment: Yes, it is - or you could say _Both aim to balance..._